# socketstream tutorials/authentication can't use Everyauth with the chat demo

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpc, everyauth, socketstream

https://socketstream.github.io/socketstream/docs/#/tutorials/authentication

when i put the codes in this section to the demo project(real time chat), the chat function doesn't work. can any one help me with this?
here's my code:

// ===================== SEPARATOR ============

```
var ss = require('socketstream');
var redirect = require('connect-redirection');
var everyauth = require('everyauth');
var http = require('http');

var conf = require('./conf/conf');
var auth_twitter = conf.oauth.twitter;

// Define a single-page client called 'main'
ss.client.define('main', {
view: 'app.html',
css: ['../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css', 'app.css'],
code: ['../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js', 'libs/jquery.min.js', 'app'],
tmpl: 'chat'
});

ss.http.middleware.prepend(redirect());

// Serve this client on the root URL
ss.http.route('/', function(req, res){
// if(!req.session.userId){ return res.redirect('/login'); }
res.serveClient('main');
});

// Use server-side compiled Hogan (Mustache) templates. Others engines available
ss.client.templateEngine.use(require('ss-hogan'));

// Minimize and pack assets if you type: SS_ENV=production node app.js
if (ss.env === 'production') ss.client.packAssets();

everyauth.twitter
.consumerKey(auth_twitter.KEY)
.consumerSecret(auth_twitter.SEC)
.findOrCreateUser( function (session, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, twitterUserMetadata) {
var userName = twitterUserMetadata.screen_name;
console.log('Twitter Username is', userName);
session.userId = userName;
session.save();
return true;
})
.redirectPath('/');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//ss.http.middleware.prepend(bodyParser.urlencoded());
//ss.http.middleware.append(everyauth.middleware());

var server = http.Server(ss.http.middleware);
server.listen(3000);
ss.start(server);
```

Comment: What's it do? Have you stepped through it in a debugger or added console.logs to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: i want to login with twitter account to the demo real time chat app, but when i add everyauth code according to the tutorial, the websocket seems not working, it's all middleware thing, so i cant's figure out debug from where

Answer (score 0):

After reading some doc, i tried this and it worked: 
replace the last three lines codes:

```
var server = http.Server(ss.http.middleware);
server.listen(3000);
ss.start(server);
```

with this:

```
ss.start();
```